# Using a URL exclusion pattern / Running App Engine in dev mode with Guice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice

I'm using GAE and Guice, but I'm running into problems on the dev server. This is my web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Everything works great until I decide to login, at which point it throws up a 404 cause it can't handle pages that start with `/_ah`. This means I can't do logins on the dev server or look  at the admin console.

Any ideas? I can't find how to add an exclusion filter to the URL matcher, and don't know which servlet GAE uses to serve development login and console :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out... I'm using regex to serve only my pages and ignore `_ah` requests.

`serveRegex("/[\\w]+").with(MainServlet.class);`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
// ignore _ah
serveRegex("^/(?!_ah.*)").with(HomeServlet.class);
```